# Why my input value is allowing me to put 3 numbers when in fact it should be 2 numbers?

Tags: javascript

When the user inputs numbers i want to allow him to put only 2 numbers.For some reason the code is allowing me to put 3 numbers and i want to know why ,Here is my  javascript code:

```
let x = document.getElementById("num");
x.addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
if(x.value<0 || x.value >99)
{
e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Comment: because you are testing a string, not a number

Answer (score 2):

You should instead use the `maxlength="2"` attribute on the input. It will restrict from entering more than 2 characters.

```html
<input type="text" id="num" maxlength="2">
```

---

But if you still want to use javascript you can check for the `input` value's length.

```js
const x = document.getElementById("num");

x.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (x.value.length > 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="num">
```

We are using `x.value.length > 1` less than `1` here because the event is fired on keypress and on the first keypress the length is `0` as there is nothing in the input.

So for the first number, the length will be `0` and for the second number it will be `1`.

Hence we are saying that if the length is more than one, which will be on the third number i.e. length is `2` and at this point in time `e.preventDefault();` will get fired.

---